# In RStudio, How to put $ (USD) Mark in GGPlot or Plotly For Numeric Row Values?

Tags: r

I have numeric values in the rows such as 1594, 1420, 989, 895, and so on. I use ggplot to visualize this data frame, and then I convert it to plotly using ggplotly() function. However, I wonder if I can change them to $1594, $1420, $989, $895, and so on on the plotly interactive chart?

I have tried some solutions such as using dollar() function from library(scales) and similar other libraries, and while they do add the dollar ($) in front of the numbers, but they also change the data type to chr. Due to this data type change, they messed up the sorting in the data frame (and visualizing them to line graph will not display the right lines). How do you add a $ sign but still everything can be sorted correctly?

I tried library(scales) with dollar() and other similar libraries

Comment: There is no need to alter your data. For example in case of axis labels you could do `scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar)` to display your numbers as dollars. The same holds adding labels via geom_text where your could use `aes(..., label= scales::dollar(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use your data as is for analysis and plotting, and then create a separate character vector for the labels

```
> a<-c(1594, 1420, 989, 895)
> b<-paste0("$",a)
> b
[1] "$1594" "$1420" "$989"  "$895"
```